# The weyl group as a dihedral group

Tags: lie-algebras, weyl-group

I am traying to solve problem 9.4 of humphreys lie algebra book and I need to show that the Weyl groups of $A_1 \times A_1$ $A_2$ $B_2$ and $G_2$ are dihedral of order 4,6,8,12.

My question is, how can a reflection group be a dihedral group since every element in a reflection group is of order two?

Comment: A reflection group is *generated* by a set of reflections, not a group that *is* a set of reflections. (For what it's worth, every group has at least one element that has order different from two...)

Comment: @SteveKass Indeed in "odd" cases the products of reflections are not reflections (akin to odd permutations multiplying to give an even permutations). Even in two dimensions, two reflections combine to give a direct isometry, which must be a rotation.

Comment: $D_3$ has 3 elements of order 2, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6

Comment: yes sorry I realized my mistake right after I made coment

Comment: @MarkBennet Any further hints on how to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

For $A_1$X $A_1 $, consider the Weyl group: $\{Id, \sigma_\alpha, \sigma_\beta, \sigma_\alpha \sigma_\beta\}$.($ Id $ is identity map)

It's group of order 4. It satisfies the properties of Dihedral group, you can verify it!